# Create a new column by combining information from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

How could I create the "message" column that incorporates information from other columns? The dataframe is already sorted in every way.

```
df   head        members   
0   Abba As      Ally       
1   Abba As      Apo
2   Abba As      Abba
3   Bella Bi     Bella
4   Bella Bi     Boo
5   Bella Bi     Brian
6   Abba As      Arra       
7   Abba As      Alya
8   Abba As      Abba
```

Expected Output

```
df  head                           message
0   Abba As          Hi Abba, we invite you, Ally and Apo. Please use "Abba As" when arriving.
1   Bella Bi         Hi Bella, we invite you, Boo and Brian. Please use "Bella Bi" when arriving.
2   Abba As          Hi Abba, we invite you, Arra and Alya. Please use "Abba As" when arriving.
```

I tried creating a first name column:

```
df["head_first_name"] = df.head.str.split(" ").str[0]
df.loc[df.head_first_name.isin(df.members)
```

Comment: Does your input always contain 3 members for a given head or can this vary?

Comment: The problem is not clear, how does your expected output related to what you come up with?

Comment: There can 'be more than 3 members

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) with a custom function:

```
def message(g):
    head = g.name[0].split()[0]
    others = ' and '.join([m for m in g['members'] if m != head])
    return f'Hi {head}, we invite you, {others}. Please use "{g.name[0]}" when arriving.'

group = df['head'].ne(df['head'].shift()).cumsum()
out = (df.groupby(['head', group], sort=False)
         .apply(message)
         .droplevel(1)
         .reset_index(name='message')
      )
```

Output:

```
       head                                                                       message
0   Abba As     Hi Abba, we invite you, Ally and Apo. Please use "Abba As" when arriving.
1  Bella Bi  Hi Bella, we invite you, Boo and Brian. Please use "Bella Bi" when arriving.
2   Abba As    Hi Abba, we invite you, Arra and Alya. Please use "Abba As" when arriving.
```

Comment: How could I generalise this further to replicate normal English text: if it's two people it's just "you and Bob". If it's more than 3 people, for example, it's "you, Bob, George and Fred".

Answer (score 1):

Other solution :

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'head': ['Abba As', 'Abba As', 'Abba As', 'Bella Bi', 'Bella Bi', 'Bella Bi', 'Abba As', 'Abba As', 'Abba As'],
        'members': ['Ally', 'Apo', 'Abba', 'Bella', 'Boo', 'Brian', 'Arra', 'Alya', 'Abba']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def create_message(g):
    name1 = g['members'].iloc[0]
    others = ' and '.join([g['members'].iloc[i] for i in range(1,len(g['members']))] )
    header = g['head'].iloc[0]
    return f'Hi {name1}, we invite you, {others}. Please use "{header}" when arriving.'

name_in_header=df['head'].str.split().str[0]
df = (df.assign(grp_id=(~(name_in_header == name_in_header.shift(-1))).cumsum().shift().fillna(0),
               same_id=(name_in_header == df['members'].str.split().str[0]))
      ).sort_values(by='same_id', ascending=False)

out = df.groupby(['head', 'grp_id']).apply(create_message)

print(out.droplevel(1))
```

```
head
Abba As     Hi Abba, we invite you, Ally and Apo. Please u...
Abba As     Hi Abba, we invite you, Arra and Alya. Please ...
Bella Bi    Hi Bella, we invite you, Boo and Brian. Please...
dtype: object
```

Comment: How could I generalise this further to replicate normal English text: if it's two people it's just "you and Bob". If it's more than 3 people, for example, it's "you, Bob, George and Fred".